# In angualar 8, what way can be the performance improvement in fetching data to the table

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I am using `Angular 8 and material design including table`. I fetch around 7000 rows using `route resolver` then I loop again to change the date format to time and format so users can read it wihtout worrying about UTC format. Here i have an issue. When navigating to this tab from the main tab, it takes 3 to 4 seconds to load. What I can is making a loader or better yet, performance improvement. What's out there to improve this situation?

Comment: You have a typo in the title: angular not angualar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching 7000 at once is probably not the best idea in the first place since most probably your user be able to view them at once anyway - ideally you'll want to implement some kind of paging mechanism in the back-end and fetch them by batches when needed. This will decrease the loading time.

Then, whether or not you have paging implemented on the back-end, you don't want to render 7000 rows at once as this is costly. There are two common solutions, both with different ups and downs.

- Use paging: Simply use [Material paginator](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview) as per examples, and only display limited amount of rows. You can even use custom implementation of DataSource to only transform the dates on-the-fly for the displayed records.
- Use virtual scroll: This is a bit trickier, but you can use [cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) in conjunction with `mat-table` and render only rows that are visible on the screen and some buffer for faster scrolling. There is not out-of-box implementation though yet, but you can find some nice examples in [this git issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10122).

Probably there are other ways as well, but this should give you the idea of what can be done.